# Video Graphics Editing

Tags: editing, programming, motion-graphics

By what process, graphics programming, editing or any other method can a human object in a live video be carved or cropped out of the video and the background unchanged and the video moving pixels continue in motion?

Answer (score 1):

I believe You want to delete some objects from Your scene.
Adobe After Effects recently introduced a feature allowing users to do just that:

Documentation: https://helpx.adobe.com/pl/after-effects/using/content-aware-fill.html

Video example:

If You meant anything else please clarify Your question a little bit more.

Comment: This was always possible before the content-aware fill function, it just involved a lot more work.